# JDBC driver version for Oracle 12c

Tags: jdbc, oracle12c

What is the suitable driver version to connect Oracle 12c. My java version is 1.6.

Currently I am using Oracle 11G with ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.0 for JDBC connectivity. 
Now I am upgrading to Oracle latest version. So I want to know which version of jdbc driver is suitable for connectivity

Comment: Go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html and download the latest...

Comment: The compatibility between Oracle database versions and the driver versions is documented here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/index.html

Comment: For JDK1.6, you should be using ojdbc6.jar. Check out the FAQ ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the link is not working

Comment: ojdbc6-12.1.0.2.0 is the suitable driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ojdbc6-12.1.0.2.0 is the suitable driver.